# Get Azure service bus queue status using NServiceBus

Tags: c#, nservicebus, .net-4.7

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50267687/2063755 provides the following code to get the queue status:

```
string connectionString = "connection string";
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var queueDescription = namespaceManager.GetQueue("queue name");
var status = queueDescription.Status;
```

How can I do that using NServiceBus?

I was hoping to use `IEndpointInstance` but it doesn't have many methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NServiceBus doesn't provide queue status. If you need the status of the queue, you will have to use the native Azure Service Bus SDK and `NamespaceManager` or [`ServiceBusAdministrativeClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet), depending on what SDK you're using.

The latest version of NServiceBus uses the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` SDK. To read the status of a queue `queue` the following would be needed:

```cs
var admin = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
QueueProperties props = await admin.GetQueueAsync("queue");
var status = props.Status
```